# How can I click a button in VB and then can be able to type in the text box?

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox, onclick

This question is about having a button and text box. And when you click the button, the text in the text box then can be written on, in one quick move. I'm building this code in VB (Microsoft, Visual Basic 2010).

`Textbox` is `disabled` by default when user click's the button  `textbox` should be `enabled`

```
Private Sub btnKey_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnButtons.Click
[...]
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set up a TextBox so that it cannot be written in (i.e., it's not enabled) until a button is clicked?  Is this ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, MVC...?

Comment: im trying to ask; when i click on a button. it then takes me to type in a text box.

Comment: You need to change the focus in the button event click handler.  Exactly how you do that may vary depending on what type of app you are writing.

Comment: and its (Microsoft, Visual Basic 2010)

Comment: Visual Basic 2010 doesn't tell me what **kind** of app you are writing.  It simply tells me what language you are using.

Comment: (Microsoft, Visual Basic 2010 express administrator?)

Comment: When you created your project, did you select Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET web site, MVC?  What type of project are you creating?

Comment: windows form application

Comment: SysDragon's question below is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub btnKey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnButtons.Click
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You!!. i was trying to search for that for 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Have your textbox enabled set to false from the start.

```
textbox1.Enabled = false
```

And at your btnKey_Click set it to true

```
textbox1.Enabled = true
```

If this is what you are asking for you realy could have spend some time on google or msdn.